# Yosemite: can't get apps on Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I upgraded from Mac OS Mavericks 10.9.5 to Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.1 and have issues with Mac App Store.

If I search for an item, I get results, but if I click a result, I get a blank page, whatever the app's page I want to see.

[image]

As you can see, the classic app background doesn't even appear.

I do not experience this issue on a fresh install of Yosemite in another mac, so I did bought my app on the other mac and used the search results's menu to install it on the right one, but that's quite tricky.

I tried to reboot, to reset the PRAM and other stuffs I seen over the internet, but didn't found any good answer.

FYI:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option and restart the Mac App Store.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this feature, nice. Anyway, after a reset, I still get a blank page.